# grunt: watch command never runs when including other tasks in registerTask method

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm having some unexpected behavior with my Gruntfile.  I've registered a task that looks like this: `grunt.registerTask('dev', ['jekyll:server', 'watch:jekyll'])` with the hopes that it will sequentially start a jekyll server, and then watch my project for specific file changes (using the `grunt-contrib-watch` plugin).   Once it detects those changes, it would re-run `jekyll:server` automatically.

The problem I'm having is that when I run `grunt dev`, it will start the Jekyll server, but it will not run the `watch` commands.  However, if I remove the server task from `grunt dev`, it will run the `watch` command as expected.

Below is the contents of my Gruntfile.  Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    jekyll: {
      server : {
        server: true,
        server_port: 4000,
        exclude: ['node_modules']
      },
      prod: {
        dest: './_site-release'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      jekyll: {
        files: ['_posts/**/*.md', '_layout/*.html', '_includes/*.html', 'index.html'],
        tasks: ['jekyll:server']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'jekyll:server');
  grunt.registerTask('dev', ['jekyll:server', 'watch:jekyll']);
  grunt.registerTask('release', 'jekyll:prod');
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `server` option makes the task block since it's persistent. You can either use the tasks [`watch` option](https://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll#watch) or something like [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) to run `jekyll` and `watch` concurrently:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    concurrent: {
        target: {
            tasks: ['jekyll:server', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent:target']);
```